# SharePoint 2007/2010 - Slide-Level Restrict from Editing (vs. Presentation-level Restriction)

Tags: 2007, 2010

We are trying to determine if there is an ability to restrict editing of PowerPoints at the slide- or section-level (versus Presentation level), specifically to allow a set of users to edit content on particular slides/sections, say by locking them as final, while allowing other users to add in/modify other slides. Our network environment utilizes AD, but may be distributed to external clients as well.

Currently our process is to extract the slides as images and then staple them back together, but are looking for a less hackish means by which to accomplish this task.

Thank you in advance for any input or ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Slides library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-slide-library-HA010174117.aspx) to have the presentation broken out into slides and can then apply Item Level Permissions as needed.